# WhenEvent error in NDSolve ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, physics, event-detection

I wish to change the term, T'[t] to 0 when S[t]<=0 when I solve ODEs. I have used WhenEvent in my NDSolve part, but it seems not work. The code is

```
Nrmlphoton[t_] = 4.64903*10^22*Piecewise[{{5904.29 t + 3.13641*10^8 t^2 - 7.0716*10^12 t^3 + 5.50886*10^16 t^4 - 
 1.91492*10^20 t^5 + 2.51145*10^23 t^6, 
   0 <= t < 0.0002274269422873725`}, {-2.86583*10^6 t + 1.69452*10^10 t^2 - 4.01716*10^13 t^3 + 
 4.77113*10^16 t^4 - 2.83738*10^19 t^5 + 6.75503*10^21 t^6, 
   0.0007374377891266094` < t < 0.0009481855159674386`}, {6.63274*10^6 t - 2.17507*10^10 t^2 + 2.82046*10^13 t^3 - 
 1.81037*10^16 t^4 + 5.75833*10^18 t^5 - 7.26732*10^20 t^6,
    0.0014995956366184178` < t < 0.0016925447841110407`}, {0, 
   0.0002274269422873725` <= t <= 0.0007374377891266094`}, {0, 
   0.0009481855159674386` <= t <= 0.0014995956366184178`}, {0, 
   t >= 0.0016925447841110407`}}]

OpticCoupl = 0.5;
ISCEff = 0.625;
w = 2 Pi 1.45 10^9;
Q = 3.5 10^3;
(**Tres = Q/w;**)
(**q0 =(Exp[6.63 10^-34 1.45 10^9/(1.38 10^-23 298)]-1)^-1**)
q0 = 4277;
qthermal = 4277;
B = 4 10^-8;
Kx = 2.7 10^4;
Ky = 0.6 10^4;
Kz = 1.7 10^3;
Wxz = 1.1 10^4;
Wyz = 2.2 10^4;
Wxy = 4.4 10^3;
Px = 0.76;
Py = 0.16;
Pz = 0.08;
Ns = 2.8 10^17;
sol = NDSolve[{T'[t] == Nrmlphoton ISCEff OpticCoupl, 
   S'[t] == -T'[t] + Kx X[t] + Ky Y[t] + Kz Z[t], 
   X'[t] == 
    T'[t] Px - X[t] Kx - (X[t] - Z[t]) Wxz - (X[t] - Y[t]) Wxy - 
     B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], 
   Y'[t] == 
    T'[t] Py - Y[t] Ky - (Y[t] - Z[t]) Wyz - (Y[t] - X[t]) Wxy, 
   Z'[t] == 
    T'[t] Pz - Z[t] Kz + (X[t] - Z[t]) Wxz + (Y[t] - Z[t]) Wyz + 
     B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], 
   q'[t] == -(w/Q)  (q[t] - qthermal) + B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t],
   q[0] == q0, X[0] == Y[0] == Z[0] == T[0] == 0, S[0] == Ns, 
   WhenEvent[S[t] <= 0, T'[t] -> 0]}, {X, Y, Z, q, S}, {t, 0, 0.002}]
```

I got the error:

> NDSolve::svnder: The variables {T'} in (T'])[t]->0 cannot be set as state variables while solving as an ODE because some are the highest order derivatives. You may be able to use these if you solve as a system of DAEs by using Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.

After using the Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}, the code cannot run at all.

> NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at t == 0.`; unable to continue.

May I ask for some help? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome here. Unfortunately, you code has syntax errors. Could you fix those please.

Comment: @Wuritianoo Not clear what you want? If `S[t]< =0`, then we assume `T' [t]=0`. But then again `S[t]>0`. In this case, we assume $T'(t)\ne 0$ or leave `T'[t]=0`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Hi Alex, thanks for your reply! In my case, I would like to let ```T'[t]=0``` when ```S[t]<=0``` and when ```S[t]>0```, still keep the function ```T'[t] == Nrmlphoton ISCEff OpticCoupl```.

Comment: @user21 Hi, thanks for notifying me the syntax errors. I have edited the piecewise function ```Nrmlphoton``` in my original post. It should now doesn't have syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem it is necessary to use damping near `S[t] = 0`. Here used function `(1 + Tanh[S[t]/10^8])/2`.

```
Nrmlphoton[t_] := 
 4.64903*10^22*
  Piecewise[{{5904.29 t + 3.13641*10^8 t^2 - 7.0716*10^12 t^3 + 
      5.50886*10^16 t^4 - 1.91492*10^20 t^5 + 2.51145*10^23 t^6, 
     0 <= t < 0.0002274269422873725`}, {-2.86583*10^6 t + 
      1.69452*10^10 t^2 - 4.01716*10^13 t^3 + 4.77113*10^16 t^4 - 
      2.83738*10^19 t^5 + 6.75503*10^21 t^6, 
     0.0007374377891266094` < t < 
      0.0009481855159674386`}, {6.63274*10^6 t - 2.17507*10^10 t^2 + 
      2.82046*10^13 t^3 - 1.81037*10^16 t^4 + 5.75833*10^18 t^5 - 
      7.26732*10^20 t^6, 
     0.0014995956366184178` < t < 0.0016925447841110407`}, {0, 
     0.0002274269422873725` <= t <= 0.0007374377891266094`}, {0, 
     0.0009481855159674386` <= t <= 0.0014995956366184178`}, {0, 
     t >= 0.0016925447841110407`}}]
OpticCoupl = 0.5;
ISCEff = 0.625;
w = 2 Pi 1.45 10^9;
Q = 3.5 10^3;
(**Tres=Q/w;**)(**q0=(Exp[6.63 10^-34 1.45 10^9/(1.38 10^-23 \
298)]-1)^-1**)q0 = 4277;
qthermal = 4277;
B = 4 10^-8;
Kx = 2.7 10^4;
Ky = 0.6 10^4;
Kz = 1.7 10^3;
Wxz = 1.1 10^4;
Wyz = 2.2 10^4;
Wxy = 4.4 10^3;
Px = 0.76;
Py = 0.16;
Pz = 0.08;
Ns = 2.8 10^17; 
sol = NDSolve[{T'[
     t] == (1 + Tanh[S[t]/10^8])/2 Nrmlphoton [t] ISCEff OpticCoupl, 
   S'[t] == -T'[t] + Kx X[t] + Ky Y[t] + Kz Z[t], 
   X'[t] == 
    T'[t] Px - X[t] Kx - (X[t] - Z[t]) Wxz - (X[t] - Y[t]) Wxy - 
     B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], 
   Y'[t] == 
    T'[t] Py - Y[t] Ky - (Y[t] - Z[t]) Wyz - (Y[t] - X[t]) Wxy, 
   Z'[t] == 
    T'[t] Pz - Z[t] Kz + (X[t] - Z[t]) Wxz + (Y[t] - Z[t]) Wyz + 
     B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], 
   q'[t] == -(w/Q) (q[t] - qthermal) + B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], 
   q[0] == q0, X[0] == Y[0] == Z[0] == T[0] == 0, S[0] == Ns}, {T, X, 
   Y, Z, q, S}, {t, 0, 0.002}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
{Plot[T[t] /. sol, {t, 0, .002}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "T"}], 
 Plot[S[t] /. sol, {t, 0, .002}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "S"}], 
 Plot[X[t] /. sol, {t, 0, .002}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "X"}], 
 Plot[Y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, .002}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Y"}], 
 Plot[Z[t] /. sol, {t, 0, .002}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Z"}], 
 Plot[q[t] /. sol, {t, 0, .002}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "g"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot for your help! Your plots are indeed what I want, however, when I ran your code, I got the error "NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.00007564216449103049`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected." Are there any specific settings I need for running the code? Thank you!
May I ask is it

Comment: I have solved the singularity issue by changing ```(1 + Tanh[S[t]/10^8])/2``` to ```(1 + Tanh[S[t]/10^9])/2```. Now the code seems work.

Comment: Given the very large values of the dependent variables, does this smooth approximation actually result in `T'[t]==0` when `S[t]==0`?  Zooming in on the first graph on `{t, 0, 0.0001}`, I'm not sure it does.  Also, check out `Plot[(1 + Tanh[S[t]/10^9])/2 /. sol, {t, 0, 0.0001}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]`.

Comment: @Wuritianoo What is your version?

Comment: @AlexTrounev My version is Mathematica 11.0.1.0 Mac OS.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks a lot for spotting it! I think you are right, may I ask is there any alternative way to get the event ```S[t]<=0, T'[t]->0``` to work? Thank you!

Comment: @Wuritianoo My example for version 12. I will check what can be done for your version.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks Alex! According to the comments of Chris, I have double checked the plots and the event seems still not behave properly, may I ask is it possible to improve the current one? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have time to get into this question in detail, but seems that the solution might bounce back and forth between `S[t]<0` and `S[t]>0` infinitely quickly, which might be a source of numerical difficulty.  Is this the kind of behavior you anticipate?  Maybe @AlexTrounev's approximation is OK given this.

Comment: @Wuritianoo  You try to see `S[t]` on a scale of 1, while it changes on a scale of $10^{17}$. I do not think it makes sense.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks for your reply! The condition I would like to achieve is that, when ```S[t]<=0```, all ```T'[t]``` in the coupled differential equations completely vanishes (i.e. ```->0```) but other terms stay for continuing the evaluation. In principle, after a certain time, ```S[t]``` will be larger than 0 again and the odes will be solved with the ```T'[t]``` term.

Comment: @Wuritianoo I suspect that the "certain time" when `S[t]` becomes larger than 0 again may be infinitesimal, leading to rapid alternation between states.  Discontinuous differential equations can be tricky like that!

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks a lot! Maybe I will still keep Alex's code to see whether the results make senses in physics.

Comment: @Wuritianoo Unfortunately I did not find the installed version 11.01. For version 10.3, we need to add option `Method -> "BDF"` and we can take `(1 + Tanh[S[t]/10^6])/2`.